# Google Developer Console IP Whitelisting

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to do IP whitelisting on GDC by adding a firewall rule for my java application. I've added to allow tcp:80 and tcp:8080 for a specific IP, but I can still access the site from outside that IP.

Are 80 and/or 8080 the ports to specify for a java app that is hosted on GCP?

TIA!

Comment: GDC sounds like Google Developers Conference (or replace Google with Game)... I assume you're using GCE (Google Compute Engine) which is part of GCP (Google Cloud Plattform). It is possible that you have these ports opened in the default network which usually isn't the place to change this kind of thing. I would start by creating my own network which only opens specific ports and assign this network to the machine (remove all others).

Comment: My application is deployed to the App Engine (.appspot.com), I haven't setup any VMs. Should the firewall rules apply to the App Engine too?

Comment: No they don't. I don't understand what you're doing. How do you add a firewall rule for you java application? If you're on appengine and you're not running a managed vm the only thing i can think of how to do this is a FilterServlet.

Comment: @konqi this is the answer I needed, i was not aware that the firewall rules only applied to managed VMs. Thanks!